# How to prove that $(a,b)\mapsto \frac{1}{2}((a+b)^{2}+3a+b)$ is bijective?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I'm reading Roger Penrose's "The road to reality". In chapter 16, discussing set theory and Cardinality , he mentions it is easy to construct a bijection (or "1-1 correspondence" - in his phrasing) between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$. and offers  $(a,b)\mapsto \frac{1}{2}((a+b)^{2}+3a+b)$ as an exercise to the reader. How would one go about proving something like this?

Comment: Have a look at page $9$ here (http://goo.gl/WjGRmH) for inspiration.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is fundamentally different because you're not dealing with reducible fractions and sign.

Comment: The point is we do not usually build a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ in a single step, neither the mentioned map provides it. By exploiting the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein theorem we have $|\mathbb{Q}|=|\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}|$, then by exploiting the given map and the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein theorem again we have $|\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{N}|$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I am sure the average reader of "The road to reality" doesn't know these theorems...

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I just realized that I misread the question. I thought that the provided map _actually was_ a claimed bijection, and not a building block. I'm aware of everything you've mentioned :)

Comment: @amsmath: then the claim *it is easy to construct a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ through the following map* is hiding something, because the shown map only gives a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$. Or between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ with a minor tweak, but still, $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\neq\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\neq\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Well, Roger Penrose is a physicist. ;-)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Which number is not covered by this map, acting only on coprime $a,b$?

Comment: @amsmath: $48$, for instance, which is the image of $(3,6)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio And why is $48$ not covered by the map? Is it injective?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Ok, I got it now (by looking at the grid below). But have you also taken into account negative values for $a$. We are talking $\mathbb Q$, not $\mathbb Q_+$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio For example, $f(-5,12) = f(2,4) = 23$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JackD'Aurizio's resource mentions, these kind of bijections often use diagonalization. In your example, write a small grid:

$$\begin{matrix}
(0, 0)&(0, 1)&(0,2)&(0,3)&(0,4)&(0, 5)\\
(1, 0)&(1, 1)&(1,2)&(1,3)&(1,4)&(1, 5)\\
(2, 0)&(2, 1)&(2,2)&(2,3)&(2,4)&(2, 5)\\
(3, 0)&(3, 1)&(3,2)&(3,3)&(3,4)&(3, 5)\\
(4, 0)&(4, 1)&(4,2)&(4,3)&(4,4)&(4, 5)\\
(5, 0)&(5, 1)&(5,2)&(5,3)&(5,4)&(5, 5)
\end{matrix}$$

Now apply the given bijection. What do you notice?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I see the diagonal "threading". But how does one formulate this into a formal proof? induction? (To be clear, a proof for this being a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ would be enough, I see it takes some more work to show the correspondence from pairs to rationals).

Comment: @H.Rappeport Hint: what is the size of the diagonal that starts at $(0, b)$? What is the cumulative sum of all diagonals before the one that starts at $(0, b)$? On what diagonal does $(a, b)$ lie?